# Entity framework select from two tables with different table relationship primary/foreign key scenarios

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have two sample tables:

SCENARIO 1

TABLE 1 - INGREDIENT

```
ingredientId(PK, int, not null)
userId(FK, int, not null)
timestamp(datetime, not null)
```

TABLE 2 - INGREDIENT ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

```
ingredientAdditionalInformationId(PK, int, not null)
ingredientId(FK, int, not null)
isApproved(bit, not null)
unitsConverted(bit, not null)
```

SELECT SENTENCE IN CODE BEHIND:

```
public IQueriable GetIngredientData(int ingredientId)
{
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
      var result = context.Ingredient
            .Where(i => i.ingredientId == ingredientId)
            .Select(i => new
            {
                 i.ingredientId,
                 i.userId
                 i.IngredientAdditionalInformation.FirstOrDefault(iai => iai.ingredientId = i.ingredientId).isApproved
                 i.IngredientAdditionalInformation.FirstOrDefault(iai => iai.ingredientId = i.ingredientId).unitsConverted
             });

          return result.ToList().AsQueriable();
  }
}
```

or select with join (I know that you can join with method syntax but I can write join with query method faster)

```
public IQueriable GetIngredientData(int ingredientId)
{
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
       var result = from i in context.Ingredient
            join iai in context.IngredientAdditionalInformation on i.ingredientId equals iai.ingredientId
            where i.ingredientId == 1
            select new
            {
                 i.ingredientId,
                 i.userId
                 iai.isApproved
                 iai.unitsConverted
            };         

        return result.ToList().AsQueriable();
  }
}
```

Which one is better/faster with join or FirstOrDefault() or I should write database table different like in example 2 below:

SCENARIO 2

TABLE 1 - INGREDIENT

```
ingredientId(PK, int, not null)
userId(FK, int, not null)
timestamp(datetime, not null)
```

TABLE 2 - INGREDIENT

```
ingredientId(PK, FK, int, not null) //WITHOUT PRIMARY (ingredientAdditionalInformationId) AUTO INCREMENT KEY)
isApproved(bit, not null)
unitsConverted(bit, not null)
```

Because I know that every ingredient have only one additional info...

SELECT SENTENCE IN CODE

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var result = context.Ingredient
      .Where(i => i.ingredientId = 1)
      .Select(i => new
      {
           i.ingredientId,
           i.userId
           i.IngredientAdditionalInformation.isApproved
           i.IngredientAdditionalInformation.unitsConverted
       });
}
```

I would like to know which table design is better (SCENARIO1 or SCENARIO2) for optimized select, if I really need auto increment key in ingredientAdditionalInformation if I know that there will be only one entry for every Ingredient and if this is the right way to use entity framework?

Answer (score 2):

If you're maintaining a one-to-one relationship between the two tables, then your second design is better, because it will also ensure referential integrity in your database.

You can then make the property a single navigation property in your entity framework model, and simplify your EF query as follows.  If you have lazy loading of navigational properties enabled in your model, you may be able to get away without using the include if you're

```
var result = from i in context.Ingredient.Include("IngredientAdditionalInformation") select i;
```

And then access the properties as follows:

```
i.IngredientAdditionalInformation.isApproved
```

However, do you really need an additional table? With only three properties on each I'd just combine them into one table and then you have all the properties available to you immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 2 is better since you are saying there is a one-to-one relationship between the two tables.
Another option you should explore is using Table Per Type Inheritance.  You will not need to specify eager loading using Include nor joins in this case.

Assuming your table1 = IngredientBase and table2 = Ingredients and in your context you have set up

```
public IQueryable<Ingredient> Ingredients { 
    get { return IngredientBases.OfType<Ingredient>(); } }
```

then you'll just need

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var result = context.Ingredients.Where(i => i.ingredientId = 1);
}
```

SQL wise, the 2nd select of scenario1 and scenario2 will produce nearly equivalent plans.  But performance wise, scenario2 will be better, not to mention being the right design for a 1-1 relationship tables.